# Rabbitmq management plugin access outside local host

Tags: rabbitmq, google-compute-engine, rabbitmqctl

I have rabbitmq running on a google compute instance. Is there a way for me to access the rabbitmq management plugin from a browser on my local machine?
In the compute instance I can access the same locally at localhost:15672.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out this was pretty straightforward to do and it was just a matter of exposing a particular port of the VM using a new firewall rule. After adding a firewall we just had to edit our VM and add the networking tag we used to create the firewall rule.

After that the port could be accessed using the (VMs External IP):15672

[image]